# Dropping the modulus sign in integrals of the form $\int 1/t ~dt$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In the process of solving a DE and imposing the initial condition I came up with the following question.

I've reached the stage that

$$\ln y + C = \int\left(\frac{2}{x+2}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \ln y +C=2\ln|x+2|-\ln|x+1|$$
$$\Rightarrow y=A\frac{(x+2)^2}{|x+1|}.$$

Now I had also found that the curve passes through $(-4,-3)$. Susbstituting in the expression above, we find $A=-9/4$. However, the solution in the markscheme (the problem was from a past exam) drops the modulus sign and so it gives $A=9/4$.

So my question is, why do they drop the modulus sign and when is one allowed to do so in dealing with integrals of the form $\int 1/t ~dt$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should presumably have had
$$\ln |y| + C = 2\ln |x+2| - \ln |x+1|\,, \quad\text{leading to}\quad |y| = A\frac{(x+2)^2}{|x+1|}\,.$$
Since a solution curve through $(-4,-3)$ cannot cross the lines $x=-1$ and $y=0$, we infer that throughout $y<0$ and $x<-1$, so $|y|=-y$ and $|x+1|=-(x+1)$. Thus, the solution is
$$y=\frac94\frac{(x+2)^2}{x+1}\,, \quad x<-1,\ y<0\,.$$
Check the markscheme carefully! :)

Answer (score 1):

$\ln (-x)$ does not make sense for $x>0$ so modulus sign must always be there for the function to make sense. You can get rid of modulus sign iff you know that $\ln(x)$ is used for some $x$ greater than zero(i.e. the parameter inside the function must be greater than zero.)

Like in this case if the modulus sign is not there there and $A=-9/4$ then for  $\forall x>-1$ , we have $y<0$ but then $\ln y$ does not make any sense(though we have used $\ln y$ to arrive at this equation.)

Comment: Yes, so is the markscheme wrong in dropping the sign and claiming that $A=9/4$ instead of $-9/4$?

Comment: In my view its wrong.